# Solve the differential equation $ x^4y^3=xy' + y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Using the change of the dependent variable $z = y^{−2}$, solve the differential equation:
>
> $$xy' + y = x^4y^3$$.

---

My attempt:

$$xy' + y = x^4y^3 \tag 1$$

Now dividing $(1)$ by $y^2$

$$\frac{xy'}{y^2} + \frac{1}{y} = x^4y$$

Now put $z= \frac{1}{y^2}$,

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{-2}{y^3}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2}{y^3}y'$$

$$y'=\frac{-y^3dz}{2dx}$$

$$xy' z +\frac{1}{y} = x^4y$$

After that im not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been easier to divide by $y^3$ initially instead of $y^2$. Also, instead of just replacing $\frac{1}{y^2}$ with $z$ in your first term, if you used your $y'=\frac{-y^3dz}{2dx}$ instead, you would then get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
-\frac{xyz'}{2} +\frac{1}{y} & = x^4y \\
-\frac{xz'}{2} + \frac{1}{y^2} & = x^4 \\
-\frac{xz'}{2} + z & = x^4
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

I trust you can now proceed to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

So far, you have:

$z = \frac{1}{y^2}$

$z' = -\frac{2y'}{y^3}$

Your differential equation, after dividing through by $y^3$, becomes:

$\frac{xy'}{y^3}+\frac{1}{y^2} = x^4$

So, just use your substitution to turn the above into a linear differential equation in terms of $z$ and $z'$. Then, use an integrating factor to solve it completely for $z$.

Once you do that, getting $y$ as a function of $x$ becomes an algebra problem.

I hope this assists you in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

$$
x(x y)^3=(x y)'
$$

and now making $z = xy$ we have

$$
x z^3= z'
$$

which is separable.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy'+y=(xy)'$$ calls for the rewrite

$$x=\frac{(xy)'}{(xy)^3}.$$
This can be integrated straight away.

Comment: Crossed with Cesaro.